# Reading Columns

Tags: scanf

I am working on a C code to read in three columns of numbers from an input file and then do basic math with the numbers obtained.  My input file looks like:

155.4996    38.0078       7.65

93.9968    44.9926       7.68

I am currently trying to separate columns using sscanf. To get this started I am trying to read in the columns and print just the third column to an output file.  Below is what I have right now:

```
FILE * fp;
FILE * fp2;
char *string;
char out[2000];
char read[1000];
int column1, column2, column3;

strcpy(read, "casecent");
strcpy(out, "Diff");

fp = fopen(read, "r");
fp2 = fopen(out, "w+");

while (!feof(fp))
{
    fgets(string, 1000, fp);
    sscanf(string, "%d %d %d", &column1, &column2, &column3);
    fprintf(fp2,"%d\n", column3);

}
```

I am currently getting zeros in the output file instead of numbers.  I'm sure I'm just missing something small and dumb but if you could help me out it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float` or `double` for the column variables' data types. Then use `%f` or `%lf` respectively in the format string for `sscanf`, depending on which data type you chose.

If you want to store or print the values as integers, you'll still have to read them as floats or doubles first, then convert.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much!  One quick follow up question, can you maybe help me figure out why it is reading and printing the last line of the input file twice?